# In the URL orgId, UserId, and User are not appearing in R12

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-ebs

In the R12.2.6 Oracle iProcurement screen I added one link like Catalog --

> it's defined on the $OA_HTML/US/POPNEWS.htm page

like `<a href = '/OA_HTML/jsp/por/cat.jsp' taget="_blank" > catalog</a>`

When I click the link in the URL it is like:

> http://isyg011.8000//OA_HTML/jsp/por/cat.jsp?responsibilityId=5014

but the same set up is done in 11i, but we could get:

> http://eol1a.8100//OA_HTML/jsp/por/cat.jsp
>   user=B&userId=1122&orgId=123&responsibilityId=5020

What is missing in R12?

Comment: EBS is an Oracle product that requires a lot of specialist knowledge. So you're probably better off asking this question on the Oracle TechNet forum dedicated to it. [Find it here](https://community.oracle.com/community/oracle-applications/e-business_suite/e-business-suite-technology/general_ebs_discussion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [Assigned Responsibilities are not visible to User](http://mkkoracleapps.blogspot.com/2013/10/assigned-responsibilities-are-not.html)

Following shortcut solution worked many times in 11i and R12 as well

> 1. Run the following requests in the order below:
>
>    a. "Create FND_RESP WF Roles"
>
>    b. "Sync responsibility role data into the WF table.(obsolete in R12)"
>
>    c. "Synchronize WF LOCAL tables"
>
>    d. "Workflow Directory Services User/Role Validation"
> 2. End date and associated userid, un-end date it, and change the password.
> 3. Retest the issue.

There is an exhaustive troubleshooting steps for this issue, but above solution has worked in most of the cases for me, except very few, where I had to walk that extra mile.

Make sure Workflow Background Process is properly Scheduled. Follow this for best practice on this:
http://mkkoracleapps.blogspot.com/2012/12/workflow-related-scheduled-concurrent.html

Comment: I tried these steps ..I could not find "Synchronize WF LOCAL tables" cp executed the rest of the steps , Unfortunately its the same issue

Comment: I give the bounty to you , for your suggestion :)